# Url template tag raises NoReverseMatch error but the generated url is correct

Tags: python, django, django-views, template-engine

I cannot use {% url %} to generate urls in Django templates. I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'category' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'category_name_slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['rango/category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\\w\\-]+)/$']
```

This how I'm using the tag:

```
{% url 'rango:category' category_name_slug=category.slug %}
```

This is the relative url() definition:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category')
```

The funny thing is that if I use category.**id** instead of slug it works, but of course the url generated doesn't much any category, since a "slug", not an id is expected in the view.

Even stranger if I use the tag as

```
 {% url 'rango:category' category_name_slug=category.slug as slug %}
 {{ slug }}
```

then the generate url is correct and no errors are raised.

Reading the error seems like nothing is passed as keyword arguments.

Any idea?

Comment: Since using `category.id` doesn't cause an error, `'{'category_name_slug': ''}'` suggests that you have a category that does not have a slug set. Check the values in your database.

Comment: Damn! you're right! I thought about that before and I checked by printing out the category.slug field too in the template (not showed in the code). I reviewed the output and it seemed ok. After reading your comment I rechecked again and indeed one category didn't have the slug!!! so much time lost... Feel free to publish this an answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part in the error message is

```
'{'category_name_slug': ''}'
```

That hints that either you haven't passed the category to the template correctly, or you have a category that does not have a slug set.

You say that using `category.id` doesn't cause an error, which means that you are passing the category to the template correctly.

Therefore you probably have have a category that does not have a slug set. Check the values in your database.